# Creating Pyspark dataframe on a python dictonary with special character

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a python dictionary  as below:

```
data = [{"cust_decision": "buy", "cust_details": "Easy to use"}, {"cust_decision": "buy", "cust_details": "econoimical"}, {"cust_decision":"no buy", "cust_details": "Didn’t like Product"}]
```

I am creating a pyspark df and temp view on this data as below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
spark.createDataFrame([Row(**i) for i in data]).createOrReplaceTempView("cust")
```

Now when I see the data of this temp view the special character **’** (This is not a single quote ' it's’) is changed to a different character **â**. Below is result

```
spark.table("cust").show(10,False)
+-------------+---------------------+                                           
|cust_decision|cust_details         |
+-------------+---------------------+
|buy          |Easy to use          |
|buy          |econoimical          |
|no buy       |Didnâ€™t like Product|
+-------------+---------------------+
```

But I'd like to get the character as is in every value. How can I achieve it?? **Below is expected result:**

```
+-------------+---------------------+                                           
|cust_decision|cust_details         |
+-------------+---------------------+
|buy          |Easy to use          |
|buy          |econoimical          |
|no buy       |Didn’t like Product  |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

Thanks ..

Comment: Which version of spark and python are you using?

Comment: 2.7 python version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by **`decoding`** your data dictionary to **`utf-8`**

```
data = [{"cust_decision": "buy", "cust_details": "Easy to use"}, {"cust_decision": "buy", "cust_details": "econoimical"}, {"cust_decision":"no buy", "cust_details": "Didn’t like Product"}]

decode_data=[{k: v.decode("utf-8") for k,v in i.items() } for i in data] 

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
spark.createDataFrame([Row(**i) for i in decode_data]).createOrReplaceTempView("cust")

spark.table("cust").show(10,False)
#+-------------+-------------------+
#|cust_decision|cust_details       |
#+-------------+-------------------+
#|buy          |Easy to use        |
#|buy          |econoimical        |
#|no buy       |Didn’t like Product|
#+-------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I tried this out in Spark 2.3 and Python 2.7. Even sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8') is not able to help

Comment: Yes Im running in Spark Shell

Comment: @Bjay, I have updated my answer and tested/worked in `spark-2.3 python-2.7`.